# Django REST Framework Nested Routers - Pagination not working

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, drf-nested-routers

I have a simple nested router using [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers), similar to the example on the readme page. The list view on the nested route does not paginate at all, ignoring my `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` setting. Is this by design? Do nested routes have to manually implement pagination? If I try to call `self.get_paginated_response` in my nested viewset's `list` method, I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /api/foo/13/bar/
'PageNumberPagination' object has no attribute 'page'
```

Here's my `list` method in my nested view:

```
def list(self, request, workplan_pk=None):
        milestones = self.get_queryset()
        wp = get_object_or_404(Workplan, pk=workplan_pk)
        milestones = milestones.filter(workplan=wp)
        return Response(self.get_serializer_class()(milestones, many=True, context={'request': request}).data)
```

Comment: I had nested routers pagination working, no problems. Pagination is handled by views which use a paginator, views know nothing about routing. They only get the request as a parameter. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: @Ivan what does your nested router's `list` method return? Mine returns a DRF Response object with serialized data. I'm wondering if I should be returning something else. I've updated the question to show my `list` method

Comment: Mine returned serialized paginated data. In your list you do not paginate data at all. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with routers. Routing is transparent to views, and the only thing they get is a `Request` object.

You can override `ModelViewSet.get_queryset()` like this:

```
class WorkplanMilestones(ModelViewSet):
    #...
    def get_queryset(self):
        wp = get_object_or_404(Workplan, pk=self.kwargs['workplan_pk'])
        return wp.milestones
```

I am assuming here that the url parameter is called `workplan_pk` and `milestones` is the reverse relationship for the milestone model.

This will return workplan's milestones and the rest (including pagination) is handled by `ModelViewSet`.

Comment: I understand that this should not have anything to do with routers. On the other hand if my list method does not paginate the data explicitly, where will the pagination happen? I understand from drf-nested-routers docs that I have to overwrite `list`, so don't I need to paginate there explicitly?

Comment: I will add a complete example.

Comment: @Neil the pagination happens in `list`, so if you are overriding it you will also have to handle the pagination. If you only override `get_queryset` though, `list` will do the pagination for you.